# cannot access user profile in template from user object

Tags: python, django

i've created a `UserProfile` method, which i would like to access with the user, however it does not seem to return anything even though i have set `related_name`. what am i missing?

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile_user")
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/img/avatars', default = 'static/imgs/avatars/avatar.jpeg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'UserProfile'
    fk_name = 'user'


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**template**

so far in template i have tried `{{ user.profile_user.avatar }}`, `{{ request.user.profile_user.avatar }}`

Comment: Does the according user have a profile?

Comment: yes it has i have added admin.py and i can see in admin panel it has a value in avatar field

Comment: what is the value of the html element? go with right click -> "inspect element".You maybe forgot to add `.url` like so: `{{ user.profile_user.avatar.url }}`

Comment: it is (unknown)